# WPF XAML How to disable a context menu?

Tags: wpf, xaml, contextmenu, hide

I am using an Infragistics datapresenter that apparently automatically includes a context menu when the user right-clicks text in any unbound field.  I simply want to disable this context menu for all the unbound fields.  How?  Note: I do have my own context menu setup for the datapresenter that should still function when clicking a record, but it does not appear when clicking individual fields of text as the "Auto context menu" does.  I can't just null it since i didn't create it, but using a keyless style of {x:Null} doesn't work either, it gives an error.

I added a link to sample project here: (Note in this sample i tried to sub in a context menu with no menu items, which then just has a "sliver" of a context menu- I couldn't figure out how to post a zip file to stackoverflow

[example with Auto context menu subbed by blank context menu-comment out xaml context menu to see my problem](http://community.infragistics.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/CommunityServer.Components.PostAttachments/00.00.35.18.82/ig-sample.zip))

Comment: Please post a small but complete test project that exhibits this.  Just don't include the Infragistics assemblies, some of us probably have them already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw your post on Infragistics' site and that they didn't give you an answer.  It appears it doesn't specifically support what you're looking to do.  This may be a sufficient workaround:

```
<Grid.Resources>
  <ContextMenu x:Key="cm">
    <MenuItem Header="test menu 1"/>
    <MenuItem Header="test menu 2"/>
  </ContextMenu>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type igDP:DataRecordCellArea}">
    <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource cm}"/>
  </Style>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type igEditors:XamTextEditor}">
    <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource cm}"/>
  </Style>
</Grid.Resources>
```

Comment: Thanks, I finally figured out somethign similar in conjunction with a trigger condition to only produce this custom context menu when the text isInEditMode also!